# Should I declare properties as Interfaces or as Base classes (when they implement both)?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting

I have a class using a group of properties in similar ways (only two shown in the example, for brevity).
The general behavior is defined on a base class, while the specific behavior is defined in specific interfaces

The problem is: If I declare them as base class, I have to cast them to interface to call interface methods. Now if I declare them as interface, I have to cast them to base class when I want to call base methods.

My goal when using interfaces here is to improve testability (with dependency injection, later), and to cultivate the habit of "programming to the interface", but I cannot decide which way is best, or even if the whole rationale is good in the first place.

```
public class Conductor
{
    // These properties inherit from base class
    // and implement one specific interface each:

    // declared as interface:
    IPlotterHelper  _plotter_helper = new PlotterHelper();

    // declared as base class:
    Helper _file_writer_helper = new FileWriterHelper();


    // When using handlers defined in specific interfaces:

    // have to cast this:
    this.NewFrame   += ((IPlotterHelper)_file_writer_helper).ProcessFrame();

    // but not this:
    this.NewSamples += _plotter_helper.ProcessSamples();



    // While when using handlers from the base class

    // have to cast this to the base class (since it is an interface):
    this.CommandSent += ((Helper)_plotter_helper).RunCommand;

    // but not this:
    this.CommandSent += _file_writer_helper.RunCommand;
}



internal class FileWriterHelper : Helper, IFileWriterHelper
{
    IFileWriterHelper.ProcessFrame()
    {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

internal class PlotterHelper : Helper, IPlotterHelper
{
    IPlotterHelper.ProcessSamples ()
    {
        ///
    }

    // ...
}

internal class Helper
{
    internal void RunCommand()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI don't use underscores when naming variables, except at the start (to indicate that they're fields). `_plotter_helper` is wrong, it should be `_plotterHelper` etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "specific behavior is defined in specific interfaces" as interfaces don't define behaviour?

Comment: It also would be awesome if the code you posted would actually compile. It's a dog's breakfast at the moment.

Comment: @Enigmativity I expressed myself badly. I wanted to say "polymorphism", where each interface implementer would implement a given method differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to exactly see what you're trying to do, but it seems like this might be a more suitable design:

```
public class Conductor
{
    private IPlotterHelper _plotter_helper = new PlotterHelper();

    private IFileWriterHelper _file_writer_helper = new FileWriterHelper();

    public void Conduct()
    {
        _file_writer_helper.ProcessFrame();
        _file_writer_helper.RunCommand();
        _plotter_helper.ProcessSamples();
        _plotter_helper.RunCommand();
    }
}

internal interface IHelper
{
    void RunCommand();
}

internal interface IFileWriterHelper : IHelper
{
    void ProcessFrame();
}

internal interface IPlotterHelper : IHelper
{
    void ProcessSamples();
}


internal class FileWriterHelper : Helper, IFileWriterHelper
{
    public void ProcessFrame()
    {
    }
}

internal class PlotterHelper : Helper, IPlotterHelper
{
    public void ProcessSamples()
    {
    }
}

internal class Helper : IHelper
{
    public void RunCommand()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think I didn't make myself clear while explaining, but the fact is: `RunCommand` has a common implementation defined in `Helper` (which is a very bad name now that I think about it). It's named so because the conductor gives commands to it, so that it "helps" to perform a concerted action (along with other helpers). But each specialized helper also has specialized members that do _additional_ stuff (like `ProcessSamples`, `ProcessFrames`, and these stuff are separated from the command-running functionality.

Comment: Wow, that's nice! Even if for now I am solving the problem otherwise, I believe this answers the question completely and correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When I am faced with the desire to have default behavior in an interface, I would generally consider using an abstract base class either with protected helper methods and a set of abstract interface methods or a default implementations of the "interface" methods.  This may be the case even if I start with only a single concrete implementation.

Many people treat abstract classes and interfaces as being in the same broad category of implementation options.

The problem with abstract classes is single inheritance, so we should only use an abstract class if it really is to be the base of a class hierarchy (even a shallow one).  Interfaces can be used to decorate classes (from diverse hierarchies) with common behavior.

For testing, I don't see much difference between faking with an interface and faking with an abstract class - but that might depend on your testing infrastructure.

In this case, I would use an abstract class and forget about the interface (unless it already exists, in which case you don't have any choice anyway).

Comment: Ok, that's what I ended up doing. Instead of `IPlotterHelper`, I have a straight `PlotterHelper` subclass, so I don't have to cast back to `Helper` anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces and abstract classes have the same purpose: provide abstraction. Make that abstraction coherent, and if the *base class* has public members, make sure they're also on the interface.

*But then, why would I need the abstract class or interface for?* - right. get rid of either the base class or the interface - you likely don't really *need* both. I'd drop the base class.